# packaging mongodb database with desktop app without installing mongodb server at users machine

Tags: database, mongodb, desktop-application, python-packaging

i'am building a simple desktop application in python(PyQt5) and using the mongodb as my database.
now i want to package this script into executable to distribute, here i'm in confusion that how to package database with it so user don't need to install mongodb server in their machine. can i use mongodb or there is different approach for desktop app

Answer (score 0):

The license allows you to distribute MongoDB server binaries, you still need to manage the process lifetime (start/stop).